# Suppose $f$ is analytic on the deleted neighborhood $N_0(z_0,r)$. Show that $f$ is bounded on $N_0(z_0,r') \iff \lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)$ exists.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic on the deleted neighborhood $N_0(z_0,r)$.

Show that $f$ is bounded on $N_0(z_0,r')$ for some $0<r'<r \iff \lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)$ exists.

$\leftarrow$ direction can be seen by using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit.

How do i show the $\rightarrow$ direction ?

Comment: Hint: Consider $h(z):=\begin{cases}(z-z_0)^2f(z) & \text{for }z\neq z_0, \\ 0 & \text{for }z=z_0.\end{cases}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sranthrop has indicated, $h(z)/(z-z_{0})=(z-z_{0})f(z)$ for $z\ne z_{0}$. Since $f$ is bounded on the deleted neighbourhood, taking $z\rightarrow z_{0}$, $h'(z_{0})$ exists and equals to $0$:

Say, $|f(z)|\leq M$ for all $z\ne z_{0}$, $z$ closed enough to $z_{0}$, then $|(z-z_{0})f(z)|\leq M|z-z_{0}|$, taking $z\rightarrow z_{0}$ and use Squeeze Theorem we get $(z-z_{0})f(z)\rightarrow 0$.

Since $h$ is also differentiable on the neighbourhood, $h$ is analytic at $z=z_{0}$, so $h(z)=\dfrac{1}{2}(z-z_{0})^{2}h''(z_{0})+\cdots$, so $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{2}h''(z_{0})+\cdots$ on the deleted neighbourhood, hence $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_{0}}f(z)=\dfrac{1}{2}h''(z_{0})$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I understand the proof except one part, why "$f$ is bounded on the deleted neighborhood $\implies lim_{z\to z_0} h'(z_0) = 0$"?

Comment: You should make it clear when using the holomorphic $\implies$ analytic theorem.

Comment: I understand the proof now. Thanks again!